# Either not changing state or not rerendering redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, dispatch, rerender

I am dispatching an action to a reducer to change that state, however nothing is re-rending. Below is some code however since the project is small I'm including a link to the repo on [Github here](https://github.com/shanemmay/Learn-Redux-Todo-App)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import * as action from '../action';

import {addTodo} from "../action";

//this is used to get the text from the input to create a new task
let text = "";

class AddTodo extends Component
{
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="text"  id="taskText" onChange={ () => { text = document.querySelector("#taskText").value;}   }/>
                <button onClick={this.props.addTodo}>+</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
{
  return (
      {
          addTodo: () =>
          {
              //console.log(`making action with text: ${text}`);
              addTodo.payload = {text:text, completed:false};
              dispatch(addTodo);
          }
      }
  );
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddTodo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared all the related code here most people don't check your repo. In the future, try to share the related (just related code) here. If you do so, you will get faster and better answers.

I will share how you solve your problems first.

- Uncomment `TodoList` component in the `App.js` file.
- In `TodoList` component your are using the wrong state. Your todos in the `todo` reducer.

So:

```
taskList: state.list.tasks.todo.concat( state.list.tasks.completed ),
```

- You are mutating your state in `todo` reducer. Don't mutate your state.

Change the related part:

```
case "ADD_TODO":
    return { ...state, tasks: { ...state.tasks, todo: [ ...state.tasks.todo, action.payload ] } };
```

Other than those problems, you are using some bad practices. For example, why do you keep the `text` in a variable like that in your `AddTodo` component? Use the local state here, this is the proper React way.

Also, your action creators are not so properly defined. They are functions, returning an object. Now, your `AddTodo` component would be like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../action";


class AddTodo extends Component {
  state = {
    text: "",
  }

  handleChange = e => this.setState( { text: e.target.value } );
  handleSubmit = () => {
    const newTodo = { text: this.state.text, completed: false };
    this.props.addTodo( newTodo );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps =
  {
    addTodo: actions.addTodo,
  };

export default connect( null, mapDispatchToProps )( AddTodo );
```

Or even, you don't need here a separate `mapDispatchToProps` if you like. You can use the connect part like this:

```
export default connect( null, { addTodo: actions.addTodo } )( AddTodo );
```

Then, your related action creator would be like this:

```
export const addTodo = newTodo => ({
  type: "ADD_TODO",
  payload: newTodo
});
```

So, I suggest reading more good tutorials about Redux :) Just give yourself a little bit more time. Follow some good tutorials until you are sure that you know the best practices and proper ways. For example, if you study Redux, the first rule is not mutating your state. You are doing it everywhere :) Also, try to keep your state simple, not so nested.

Good luck.